# Can not add Artisan command line tool on PhpStorm 10.0.3

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I am using **PhpStorm 10.0.3** and trying for many days to add Artisan command line tool for **Laravel 5.2** but could not be able to.

I got the message as below ...

> Problem
>       Failed to determine version.
>       Command
>       `D:\Websites\php\php.exe D:\Websites\htdocs\eloquent\artisan -V`
>       Output Laravel Framework version 5.2.10

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30343

Answer (score 3):

add this line at the beginning of the artisan file (before "require **DIR**.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';"):

if (isset($argv[1]) && $argv[1] === '-V') { die('Symfony version 3.0.0'); }

Comment: Thank you **Aliaksandr Dvoineu**. It works for me now. You save my vast of time. I do it and become successful but I don't understand **_what does the above line mean_**. I just start learning **Laravel** using **PhpStorm**.

Answer (score 0):

For command line tool support of artisan add tool type as "Symfony" instead of "custom".

For more details please follow 
[official doc](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/09/command-line-tools-based-on-symfony-console-doctrine-laravel-in-phpstorm/)